# Gmail hacked, no IP alerts

Tags: gmail, google-account, security, hacked

Recently my Gmail was hacked - I was suddenly signed out of Gtalk and my password no longer worked.

I was able to reset my password by following my secret question/answer. When I logged in again, I checked the IP security monitor and nothing but my IP has connected recently. I'm 99% positive I know the identity/e-mail of the person who hacked my account - a friend of someone I was talking to who became upset at me for talking to their friend too much.

I have never talked to this person or GChat.

What security vulnerabilities does Google, or Gtalk have that would give access to change my password? And can I report this to Google - I couldn't find a form on their website.

Please note I am not interested in "hacking back" or anything like that.

Answer (score 6):

It was probably just a server error at Google and you're being paranoid.

Comment: Never happened before, and it happened within minutes of receiving the threatening/rude e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be a trojan sitting on your computer. It theoretically could change your google password, so just to be safe, check your PC for viruses.

But I agree with jason here, most likely, this was just a google error. =)